# Что означает условие ... && 'false' == 'false'?

Tags: javascript

Объясните, что означает это условие; на странице форма с двумя переключателями radio.

```
function click() {
    if (document.forms[0].type[0].checked && 'false' == 'false') {
        document.forms[0].type[1].checked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: если не выбран 1-ый элемент radio (`type[0]`), выбрать (=«включить»)второй элемент radio (`type[1]`)

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, условие `'false' == 'false'` эквивалентно условию `true`, тоесть смысла в нём совсем нет. Или я не прав?

Comment: это условие срабатывает также если выбран первый элемент (type[0])

Comment: @Crasher, прав. Это могло быть кунг-фу про undefined или null в checked. но данная конъюнкция бессмысленна ибо ни null ни undefined не меняет к true или false.

Comment: индусский код чистой воды:

    true && 'false' == 'false' => true
    false && 'false' == 'false' => false

следовательно можно было оставить только первую часть условия

Comment: ни null ни undefined не меняет к true или false???

    !undefined === true
    !null === true

Если`document.forms[0].type[0].checked` будет равен `undefined` либо `null`, то в `if` мы не попадем, соответственно мне не совсем ясна эта фраза...

#####я знаю что кэп бессилен, я сегодня подменяю

Comment: @AlexWindHope "данная конъюнкция не меняет..." косноязычие - мой конек :)

Answer (score 5):

Скорее всего, если заглянуть в исходный код, увидите что-то типа:
Вариант на PHP

```
?>
function click() {
    if (document.forms[0].type[0].checked && '<?php echo $config['ALLOW_TYPE_0']?>' == 'false') {
        document.forms[0].type[1].checked = true;
    }
}
<?php
```

Тоесть если в настройках скрипта PHP запрещено выбирать 1-ый пункт, JS переключает на второй.
PS Приведенный пример жуткий быдлокод, так делать НЕЛЬЗЯ! Но подобное очень часто встречается, к сожалению...